# Remove from Multi-FASTA by Sequence ID

Tags: fasta, linux, shell, awk, multiple-sequence-alignment

I want to remove sequence VRE32514 – it doesn’t belong and thus is the reason it lacks additional metadata. However I tried implementing this [code](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/13126/remove-sequences-from-fasta-file-matching-a-string-in-the-header) from a similar question:

```
awk 'BEGIN{while((getline<">VRE32514")>0)l[">"$1]=1}/^>/{f=!l[$1]}f' *.fasta | grep -v ">VRE32514" *.fasta
```

With no success and the proposed solution in R using `seqinr` doesn't seem to work either for myself.

```
#load package
library(seqinr)
#load file containing sequences
data<-read.fasta("test.fasta")
#create a vector containing species names: these are the last part of the string
vec.names<-unlist(lapply(strsplit(names(data), "|"), function(x)x[length(x)]))
#find names to keep: indices which are not in the species to remove
species.to.remove<-c(">VRE32514")
vec.tokeep<-which(! vec.names %in%  species.to.remove)
#write the final output
write.fasta(sequences=data[vec.tokeep], names=names(data)[vec.tokeep], file.out="output.fasta")
```

Below is an example of what my Multi-FASTA appears as and the desired output:

```
>VRE32491|736|PUH-10C|Blood|2016-12-07
ATGAGATCAGAAAAAGAAATGATGGATTTAGTACTTTCTTTAGCAGAACAGGATGAACGT
ATTCGAATTGTGACCCTTGAGGGGTCACGCGCAAATATTAATATACCTAAAGATGAATTT
>VRE32493|1471|PUH-10N|Tissue/Surgical|2016-12-08
CAGGATTATGATATTACATATTTTGTAAGTGATATAGAACCGTTTATATCTAATGATGAC
TGGCTTAATCAATTTGGGAATATAATAATGATGCAAAAGCCGGAGGATATGGAATTATTC
CCACCTGAAGAAAAGGGATTTTCCTATCTTATGCTATTTGATGATTACAATAAAATTGAT
>VRE32503|1471|PUH-11N|Wound|2017-01-05
CTTACCTTATTGCCCTTGGAAGAGTTAGATAATTACCTAAAGGGCGATAAATTAATAAAG
GTTCTAATTGATAAAGATTGTAGAATTAAAAGGGACATAGTTCCGACTGATATAGATTAT
>VRE32504|1471|PUH-EMEP|Blood|2017-01-10
CATGTAAGAAAGCCAAGCGCAAGGGAGTATGATGATTGCTGCAATGAATTTTGGAATGTA
ACACCTTATGTTATTAAAGGATTGTGCCGTAAGGAAATTTTATTTGCTATTGATCATTTT
>VRE32514
AATCAGATTGTTCGCCATGAGCTGCTGAGAATGATATCATGGAAGGGCGGCATCGAAACA
GGCTTTAAATTAAGTGTAGGCAAGAACTATAAGTTTATTGAAAGGTATATATCCGAGGAT
```

Desired Output:

```
>VRE32491|736|PUH-10C|Blood|2016-12-07
ATGAGATCAGAAAAAGAAATGATGGATTTAGTACTTTCTTTAGCAGAACAGGATGAACGT
ATTCGAATTGTGACCCTTGAGGGGTCACGCGCAAATATTAATATACCTAAAGATGAATTT
>VRE32493|1471|PUH-10N|Tissue/Surgical|2016-12-08
CAGGATTATGATATTACATATTTTGTAAGTGATATAGAACCGTTTATATCTAATGATGAC
TGGCTTAATCAATTTGGGAATATAATAATGATGCAAAAGCCGGAGGATATGGAATTATTC
CCACCTGAAGAAAAGGGATTTTCCTATCTTATGCTATTTGATGATTACAATAAAATTGAT
>VRE32503|1471|PUH-11N|Wound|2017-01-05
CTTACCTTATTGCCCTTGGAAGAGTTAGATAATTACCTAAAGGGCGATAAATTAATAAAG
GTTCTAATTGATAAAGATTGTAGAATTAAAAGGGACATAGTTCCGACTGATATAGATTAT
>VRE32504|1471|PUH-EMEP|Blood|2017-01-10
CATGTAAGAAAGCCAAGCGCAAGGGAGTATGATGATTGCTGCAATGAATTTTGGAATGTA
ACACCTTATGTTATTAAAGGATTGTGCCGTAAGGAAATTTTATTTGCTATTGATCATTTT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `samtools faidx` to first index your file and then retrieve only those sequences you specify. For this `grep` all the sequence headers you want and then remove the unwanted ones, followed by retrieval of the fasta entries with `faidx`:

```
#/ index:
samtools faidx your.fa

#/ run:
grep '^>' test.fa \             # grep names
| grep -v '>VRE32514' \         # remove unwanted
| tr -d '>' \                   # remove ">" from name
| xargs samtools faidx your.fa  # get the entries you want
```

Output:

```
>VRE32491|736|PUH-10C|Blood|2016-12-07
ATGAGATCAGAAAAAGAAATGATGGATTTAGTACTTTCTTTAGCAGAACAGGATGAACGT
ATTCGAATTGTGACCCTTGAGGGGTCACGCGCAAATATTAATATACCTAAAGATGAATTT
>VRE32493|1471|PUH-10N|Tissue/Surgical|2016-12-08
CAGGATTATGATATTACATATTTTGTAAGTGATATAGAACCGTTTATATCTAATGATGAC
TGGCTTAATCAATTTGGGAATATAATAATGATGCAAAAGCCGGAGGATATGGAATTATTC
CCACCTGAAGAAAAGGGATTTTCCTATCTTATGCTATTTGATGATTACAATAAAATTGAT
>VRE32503|1471|PUH-11N|Wound|2017-01-05
CTTACCTTATTGCCCTTGGAAGAGTTAGATAATTACCTAAAGGGCGATAAATTAATAAAG
GTTCTAATTGATAAAGATTGTAGAATTAAAAGGGACATAGTTCCGACTGATATAGATTAT
>VRE32504|1471|PUH-EMEP|Blood|2017-01-10
CATGTAAGAAAGCCAAGCGCAAGGGAGTATGATGATTGCTGCAATGAATTTTGGAATGTA
ACACCTTATGTTATTAAAGGATTGTGCCGTAAGGAAATTTTATTTGCTATTGATCATTTT
```

In `R` one could use `Biostrings`:

```
library(Biostrings)

fasta <- readDNAStringSet("path/to/your.fa")
fasta_new <- fasta[!names(fasta) %in% c("VRE32514")]

#/ save to disk:
writeXStringSet(fasta_new, "path/to/outputfile.fa")
```

Comment: Your solution in `R` using `Biostrings works perfectly, thank you! However I couldn't understand how to get your `UNIX` solution to work. When I enter `grep '^>' example.fasta | grep -v '>VRE32514' | tr -d '>' | xargs samtools faidx example.fasta` I get the following error message: \n `not found in FASTA file, returning empty sequenceood|2016-12-07
>VRE32491|736|PUH-10C|Blood|2016-12-07
[faidx] Failed to fetch sequence in VRE32491|736|PUH-10C|Blood|2016-12-07`

Comment: @MicroBiostat It works fine on my machine. Maybe something odd wirh your fasta, e.g. empty lines somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using Python:

````py
from Bio import SeqIO

sequences = SeqIO.parse('test.fasta', 'fasta')
filtered = [seq for seq in sequences if 'VRE32514' not in seq.id]

with open('output.fasta', 'wt') as output:
    SeqIO.write(filtered, output, 'fasta')
```
````